# How to read integer in Erlang?

Tags: input, erlang, integer

I'm trying to read user input of integer. (like cin >> nInput; in C++)
I found io:fread bif from http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html, so I write code like this.

> {ok, X} = io:fread("input : ",
> "~d"),
>  io:format("~p~n", [X]).

but when I input 10, the erlang terminal keep giving me "\n" not 10. I assume fread automatically read 10 and conert this into string. How can I read integer value directly? Is there any way to do this? Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
1> {ok, [X]} = io:fread("input : ", "~d").
input : 10
{ok,"\n"}
2> X.
10
3> {ok, [A,B]} = io:fread("input : ", "~d,~d").
input : 456,26
{ok,[456,26]}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 4):

There are various functions in OTP to help you convert a string to an integer. If you just read a string from the user (until newline for example) you can the evaluate it with the function `to_integer(String)` in the `string` module:

```
string:to_integer(String) -> {Int,Rest} | {error,Reason}
```

There is also the `list_to_integer(String)` BIF (Built-In Function, just call without a module) but it is not as forgiving as the `string:to_integer(String)` function:

```
list_to_integer(String) -> int()
```

You will get a `badarg` exception if the string does not contain an integer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use string:to_integer/1, check that the value of Rest is the empty list [].  The function extracts the integer, if any, from the beginning of the string. It does not assure that the full input converts to an integer.

```
string:to_integer(String) -> {Int,Rest} | {error,Reason}
```

An example:

```
{Int, Rest} = string:to_integer("33t").
Int.  % -> 33
Rest. % -> "t"
```

Why check? If the user's finger slipped and hit 't' instead of 5, then the intended input was 335, not 33.

Answer (score 2):

Try printing the number with `~w` instead of `~p`:

```
1> io:format("~w~n", [[10]]).
[10]
ok
2> io:format("~p~n", [[10]]).
"\n"
ok
```

The `~p` format specifier tries to figure out whether the list might be a string, but `~w` never guesses; it always prints lists as lists.

Answer (score 0):

Erlang represents strings as lists of integers that are within a certain range. Therefore the input will be a number that represents the character "1" you could subtract an offset to get the actual. Number, sorry don't have a VM here to test a solution.