# Why is [9] returned as "\t" in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am working through some Erlang tutorials and noticed when I enter

```
[8].
```

the VM returns "\b"
or if I enter

```
[9].
```

the VM returns "\t"

I am confused on why this is happening.  Other numbers are returned as a list of that number:

```
[3].
```

is returned as [3]

```
[4].
```

is returned as [4], etc.

I guess the question is why is the erlang VM return it this way?  Perhaps an explanation of a list [65] and a list? "A".
Another related item is confusing as well:
Type conversion, converting a list to an integer is done as:

```
list_to_integer("3").
```

Not

```
list_to_integer([3]).
```

Which returns an error

Comment: I am not an an Erlang developer but I noticed that 9 is the ASCII value for Tab. and 8 is the ASCII for backspace.

Comment: Yeah, I was recognizing that as well.  It would be nice to understand why it converts it like that.  I am sure they are equal.

Comment: Well "\b"=[8]. does match, so they are the same value. Interesting.

Comment: What does `[65].` return?

Comment: Almost as expected "A".

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/689006/113848).

Comment: To be precise the function **returns** `[97,98,99]` while the shell **prints** the value as `"abc"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Erlang there are no real strings. String are a list of integers. So if you give a list with integers that represent characters then they will be displayed as a string.

```
1> [72, 101, 108, 108, 111].
"Hello"
```

If you specify a list with at least element that does not have a character counterpart, then the list will be displayed as such.

```
2> [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 1].
[72,101,108,108,111,1]
```

Comment: This is really only an issue in the shell, though.  Typically you know what a list is (i.e whether it's meant to be a string or not), and you can control the output: io:format("~s~n", [[1, 2, 3]]) vs io:format("~w~n", [[1, 2, 3]]), for example.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang strings are  lists and the notation is exactly the same.

```
[97,98,99].
```

returns "abc"

The following excerpt is taken directly from "Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good!", Fred Hébert, (C)2013, No Starch Press.  p. 18.

This is one of the most disliked thins in Erlang: strings. Strings are lists, and the notation is exactly the same.  Why do people dislike it?
Because of this:

```
3> [97,98,99,4,5,6].   
[97,98,99,4,5,6]   
4> [233].   
"é"
```

Erlang will print lists of numbers as numbers only when at least one of them could not also  represent a letter.  There is no such thing as a real string in Erlang!

"Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good!" is also available online at: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/

Answer (score 1):

kadaj answered your first question. Regarding the second one about `list_to_integer`, if you look at [the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_atom-1), most `list_to_XXX` functions except `binary`, `bitstring`, and `tuple` consider their argument as a string. Calling them `string_to_XXX` could be clearer, but changing the name would break a lot of code.