# How to delete an element in a list manually?

Tags: list, erlang

I created a program that automatically deletes the element I have specified in Lst2 which is element 3. Now, I want to manually pick what element is to be deleted in the list that I will input.

```
-module(list).
-import(lists,[delete/2]).
-export([del/1]).
del([]) -> [];

del(N) -> 
    Lst1 = N,
    Lst2 = delete(3,Lst1),
    io:fwrite("~w~n",[Lst2]).
```

Comment: Look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688250/how-to-read-integer-in-erlang) question. Btw, not use explicit import. This can be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in an index when you call the `del` function will work:

```
-module(list).
-import(lists,[delete/2]).
-export([del/2]).

del(_Index, []) -> [];
del(Index, List) -> 
    List2 = delete(Index,List),
    io:fwrite("~w~n",[List2]).
```

Or, if you want to get the index from user input you can read from STDIN like this:

```
-module(list).
-import(lists,[delete/2]).
-export([del/2]).

del([]) ->
    io:format("Empty list. Nothing to remove.~n"),
    [];
del(List) -> 
    {ok, [Index]} = io:fread("Index to remove : ", "~d"),
    List2 = delete(Index,List),
    io:fwrite("~w~n",[List2]).
```